# alert is showing blank value in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

This is my jsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script src="newjavascript.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
 Name:         <input type="text" value="" id="t1"><br>
 Age:          <input type="text" value="" id="t2"><br>
 Rollno:       <input type="text" value="" id="t3"><br>
 Address:      <input type="text" value="" id="t4"><br>
<div id="er" style="color: red;"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validation()">
 </body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var st_roll_no="";

function validation()
{
if (document.getElementById("t1").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") === "")
{
    document.getElementById("er").innerHTML = "please select name";
}
else if (document.getElementById("t2").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") === "")
{
    document.getElementById("er").innerHTML = "please select age";
}
    else if (document.getElementById("t3").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") != "")
{
    fetch_rollno(document.getElementById("t3").value);
            alert("After fetching the result is "+st_roll_no);
}
      else if (st_roll_no.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") === "found")
{
    document.getElementById("er").innerHTML = "Please enter address";
}
   else if (document.getElementById("t4").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") === "")
{
    document.getElementById("er").innerHTML = "Please enter address";
}
    else
    {
        alert("success");
    }
}

function fetch_rollno(rollno)
 {
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'validate_rollno',
            data: {rollno: rollno},
            success: function(result) 
            { 
                alert("result from database is "+result);             
            if (result == "found")
                {
                    alert("if");
                    st_roll_no="found";
                    alert(st_roll_no);

                }
                else
                {
                     alert("else");
                     st_roll_no="notfound";
                     alert(st_roll_no);

                }

            }
        });
    }
```

After fetching rollno from database and setting in a global variable `st_roll_no`.This line

```
 alert("After fetching the result is "+st_roll_no);
```

is printing a blank alert.It should print `found or notfound`;

Edit---------------

This is my servlet:

```
public class validate_rollno extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
       PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
       String Status="";
       String rollno=request.getParameter("rollno");
       classes.query q=new classes.query();
       java.util.List li=q.select("select name from student where rollno='"+rollno+"'");
       java.util.Iterator it=li.iterator();
       if(it.hasNext())
       {
           Object oo=it.next();
           Status="found";
           out.println(Status);
       }
       if(li.size()==0)
       {
            Status="not found";
            out.println(Status);
       }
}
```

}

Comment: does it alert "if" or "else" ?

Comment: @johnSmith yes it returns if or else

Comment: @Andy no it is not duplicate i am receiving response from servlet as found or not found

Comment: I think you are alerting `alert("After fetching the result is "+st_roll_no);` before the ajax success call back function is executed.

Comment: @sameer so what should i do.

Comment: create a [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and call the alert in [then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
alert("After fetching the result is "+(st_roll_no? "found" : "notfound"));
```

> Update1:

```
function fetch_rollno(rollno)
{
     var st_roll_no="After fetching the result is ";    
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'validate_rollno',
                data: {rollno: rollno},
                success: function(result) 
                {
                    st_roll_no+= (result == "found") ?"found" : "notfound";
                    alert("st_roll_no");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Did you see the alert? `alert("if")` or `alert("else")`

Comment: Yes i am seeing `alert("if") or alert("else")`

Comment: @AK2 If you see the messages should too see this message.**see update in my answer**

Comment: Thanks it worked could you plz tell me why it was not working before.

Comment: Why it worked with conditional operator and why ist_rollno returning blank before

Comment: `alert("if")` and `alert("else")` It may stop initialize `st_roll_no`.